# How to send a message to every socket connection (from server)

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm trying to create a simple chat application just for the challenge and to learn javascript even more.
For this, I use the built-in package `net` to do my socket server and client.

To do it simply , I have a client that send a Stringify object when it connect to the server and I want my server to send a message to every client currently connected.

This is the structure of my message :

```
socket.write(JSON.stringify({
       type: message type,
       data: message data,
       author: message author
}))
```

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for everyone who read this.

Comment: here is a chat example with socket.io https://socket.io/demos/chat/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. This is taken from the ws github page https://github.com/websockets/ws
There are many ways to achieve this but in Node this is probably the best solution.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

// Broadcast to all.
wss.broadcast = function broadcast(data) {
wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
 if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
     client.send(data);
    }
  });
 };

 wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
 ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
 // Broadcast to everyone else.
 wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
  if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
    client.send(data);
        }
      });
    });
 });
```